# How to integrate bitcoin wallet

Tags: website-integration

I am a programmer and I am working on a website. I want to find out how to integrate a blockchain into my website. (Please note that the wallet address changes as soon as it receives a payment). I'm particular about how to resolve this issue.

Comment: This question is too broad. Can you please clarify what exactly you want to do (you can't integrate a blockchain into a website) and what software you are using as it seems you have already integrated some wallet service into your site.

Answer (score 1):

You can install your own wallet and use it ie. with RPC

Probably you will need some payment processor. There are several, just google for them and their developers guides.

Many shop solutions like ie. magento have several extensions using different technology, you can look up how they do it and build based on their implementation.

Here is one of many guides: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/adding-bitcoin-payment-processing-to-your-website--net-33098

- Blockhain.info: https://blockchain.info/api
- Bitpay: https://bitpay.com/developers
- Bitpay gateway guide: https://bitpay.com/bitcoin-payment-gateway-api
- Bitpay's API Documentation: https://bitpay.com/api

Comment: I'm developing a new bitcoin, bitcoincash payment system. It's name is https://payb.tc This is under development now but it will finish in a short time. Low fee, fast payment and withdraw properties.

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest that you learn a little more before trying to write software that utilizes bitcoin.  You're clearly not informed about many things.

For instance, your wallet address doesn't change when it receives a payment.  An additional address is generated, but the old address is still there and still can accept payments.

This is such a fundamental lack of understanding that it indicates you have almost 0 experience with bitcoin, which is why I suggest further research on your part.

You also need to understand exactly what "integrate" means to you, before you can write software to do it.